# How do I setup JavaFX with SpringBoot desktop application to share database on a LAN

Tags: spring-boot, javafx, desktop-application, hsqldb, lan

I have an inventory management application built with JavaFx and springboot that was originally built to run as standalone using hsqldb. Now I want to upgrade it so that two or more systems can share same database in a LAN environment. When I connect two systems via wifi, I could run the application from the other connected computer but after creating a record, it did not reflect on the other system. Please how do I make this work? Do I need to use mysql instead of hsqldb?
Below is my application.yml file configuration. The lines hashed out are the previous setting for the stand alone version and I have re-defined the hsql settings to use a network path as shown (\PC001\ims_compiled\shared_hsqldb\hsqldb)

Please any assistance ill be appreciated

```
app:
  fixedDelay: 300000
  fixedRate: 1200000
  localLogin: true
debug: true
hsql:
  parameters: hsqldb.lock_file=false;createDatabaseIfNotExist=true;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;shutdown=true;hsqldb.write_delay=false;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=100
log4j:
  logger:
    org:
      hibernate:
        transaction: ERROR
      springframework:
        transaction: ERROR
logging:
  config: logback.xml
  level:
    com:
      zaxxer:
        hikari:
          HikariConfig: ERROR
    org:
      hibernate:
        SQL: ERROR
        type:
          descriptor:
            sql:
              BasicBinder: ERROR
mysql-base:
  datasource:
    DB: ikooba_db
    host: 34.244.38.76
    jdbc-url: jdbc:mysql://${mysql-base.datasource.host}:${mysql-base.datasource.port}/${mysql-base.datasource.DB}?${mysql-base.datasource.parameters}
    parameters: serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=FALSE&autoReconnect=true&sessionVariables=sql_mode=''
    password: 'gsjgsgssshj'
    port: 3306
    username: sfgsdsfdfs
sentry:
  dsn: https://shfs6765676757shsvvs@errors.xxxxxxxx.com/6
  enabled: true
  stacktrace:
    app:
      packages: com.ikooba.desktop.ims
spring:
  datasource:
    hikari:
      auto-commit: true
#      jdbcUrl: jdbc:hsqldb:hsqldb/userDB;${hsql.parameters}
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:hsqldb:\\PC001\ims_compiled\shared_hsqldb\hsqldb/userDB;${hsql.parameters}

    password: ''
    username: sa
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      use-new-id-generator-mappings: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        enable_lazy_load_no_trans: true
        jdbc:
          batch_size: 120
        order_inserts: true
        search:
          default:
            directory_provider: filesystem
#            indexBase: hsqldb/lucence/indexes
            indexBase: \\PC001\ims_compiled\shared_hsqldb\hsqldb/lucence/indexes
            indexwriter:
              infostream: true
          generate_statistics: true
          jmx_enabled: true
          lucene_version: LATEST
      javax:
        persistence:
          validation:
            mode: none
  main:
    allow-bean-definition-overriding: true
    lazy-initialization: true
```

Comment: Run the hsql database on a single machine and connect to the ip and port from other machines using jdbc. See [hsql server mode](http://www.hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/running-chapt.html#rgc_hsql_server)

Answer (score 1):

Setup a HSQLDB server on PC001 and connect to it from different machines.

Chapter 15. http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_hsql_server

For simplicity, create a `server.properties file` as described. Inside this file the property setting below should reflect the name, path, and the startup properties of your databse. For example:

```
 server.database.0=file:\\PC001\ims_compiled\shared_hsqldb\hsqldb/userDB;hsqldb.write_delay_millis=100
```

The other parameters that you used in your `hsql.parameters` are unnecessary (e.g. hsqldb.lock_file, shutdown). See http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/dbproperties-chapt.html for valid properties (but you probably don't need them).